# Como cerrar automáticamente una ventana Modal CSS JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Tengo un formulario para agregar cursos a una BD, dentro de los datos solicitados esta el de relatores, el cual es un listbox que llama a la BD y muestra los relatores disponibles, y en el caso de que el relator que el usuario quiera no aparezca en el listado, agregue una opción para agregar mas relatores, el cual es un modal que solo pide nombre del relator y la entidad a la que pertenece, este luego va a un php, el cual ingresa los datos a la BD,

```
<?php
    $conex=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","capacitaciones");
    $relator_nom = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT `nombre_relator` FROM `relatores` WHERE `nombre_relator` like '$nombre_relator'");
    $result_nm_relator=0;

    if($relator_nom){
        while ($registro_relator = mysqli_fetch_array($relator_nom)){ 
            $result_nm_relator = $registro_relator['nombre_relator']; 
        }
    }

    echo $result_nm_relator;

    if ($result_nm_relator==null){
        $sql = ("
            INSERT INTO `capacitaciones`.`relatores` (`nombre_relator`, `entidad_relator`)
                VALUES ('$nombre_relator', '$entidad_relator')
        "); //Se insertan los datos a la base de datos y el usuario ya fue registrado con exito.  

        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)){ 
            scriptAlertGo('!El relator fue agregado correctamente!','#');
        }else{
            scriptAlert('!Ha ocurrido un problema en la inscripción, por favor intente nuevamente!','#');
        }      

        }else{
            scriptAlertGo('El nombre del relator ya esta registrado en la base de datos','#');
        }
    }
?>
```

Lo que me gustaría es que, una vez que esta ingresado el relator, el modal se cierre, y vuelva a cargar el listbox con el listado de relatores actualizado, ya que si reviso el listbox no aparece actualizado, y debo volver a cargar el sitio para que aparezca actualizado el listado,

Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda,

Comment: Hola @Juan, ¿podrías añadir el código de SQL de tu base de datos con algún dato de prueba para poder correr y depurar tu programa? Te animo a que lo dejes en GitHub y lo compartas conmigo para sugerirte cambios

Comment: Muchas gracias David, pero ya pude resolverlo, ahora me aparecen otros problemas relacionados a desarrollo:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244190/c%C3%B3mo-consigo-que-2-variables-con-la-misma-id-se-guarden-en-una-bd

Recien pude conseguir un hosting de prueba, así que subire el sitio para que quede visible, con el fin de poder guiar mejor,

Muchas gracias

Comment: http://www.ceotalca.cl/prueba/

Ese es el sitio de prueba

Comment: usuario y contraseña: admin