# ¿Cómo consigo que 2 variables con la misma ID se guarden en una Base de datos MYSQLI?

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Necesito de su ayuda, tengo un formulario donde inscribo los datos de un curso: `nombre`, `fecha`, `cantidad de horas`, `relator`…), en el cual me solicitaron la opción de agregar más de un `relator` al curso (este actualmente es un listbox)

```html
 <div class="col-md-6 animate-box">
     <h3>Complete los datos solicitados</h3>
     <form action="creacion_curso_bd.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" target="_self" id="form1">
      <div class="row form-group">

    <!-- nombre curso -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="nombre_curso" id="nombre_curso" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del curso">
 </div> 
      
 </div> 

            <!-- fin nombre curso -->

            <input type="hidden" id="dir" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ip_usuario; ?>"> <!-- Podría ser <?=$ip?>, como fomra abreviada -->

     <!-- Fecha del curso -->         
             <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                       <!-- <input class="form-control required" type="text" name="check_in" id="check_in" placeholder="Fecha de realización"> -->

                        <input class="form-control required" type="date" name="fecha_curso" id="fecha_curso" placeholder="Fecha de realización">
                      </div>
                    </div>
            <!-- fin Fecha del curso -->


             <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="numero_horas" id="numero_horas" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad de horas" onkeypress="return valideKey(event);" >
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="sigper" id="sigper" class="form-control" placeholder="Codigo SIGPER">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="vacantes" id="vacantes" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad de vacantes" onkeypress="return valideKey(event);" >
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="text" name="ubicacion" id="ubicacion" class="form-control" placeholder="Ubicación del curso">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <textarea name="descripcion"  id="descripcion" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripción del curso"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

     <!-- <div class="row form-group">
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <label for="subject">Subject</label> 
        <input type="text" name="curso" id="curso" class="form-control" placeholder="Curso">
       </div>
      </div>-->

       <!--     <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select name="curso" id="curso" class="form-control" >
                    <option value=''>Elija un curso</option>
                    <?php
                        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM cursos");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores[id_curso].'">'.$valores[nombre_curso].'</option>';
                        }
                       ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div> -->

            <!-- ambito -->
            <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select name="ambito" id="ambito" class="form-control" style="height: 50px" >
                    <option value=''>Elija un ambito</option>
                    <?php
                        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM ambito");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores[id_ambito].'">'.$valores[ambito].'</option>';
                        }
                       ?>

                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- fin ambito -->

            <!-- Relatores 
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select name="id_relatores" id="id_relatores" class="form-control" style="height: 50px" >
                    <option value=''>Elija un relator</option>
                    <?php
                        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM relatores");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores[id_relator].'">'.$valores[nombre_relator].'</option>';
                        }
                       ?>

                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>  

         prueba dinamica relatores -->

        <div class="row form-group" id="dynamic_form">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             
                <select name="p_name" id="p_name" class="form-control" style="height: 50px" >
                    <option value=''>Elija un relator</option>
                    <?php
                        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT id_relator, nombre_relator FROM relatores");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores[id_relator].'">'.$valores[nombre_relator].'</option>';
                        }
                       ?>
                  </select>
           
                  <div class="button-group">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary; color: #1f27ba" id="plus5">Añadir mas relatores</a>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" id="minus5">Remover Relator</a>
                  </div>
      
              <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                  var dynamic_form =  $("#dynamic_form").dynamicForm("#dynamic_form","#plus5", "#minus5", {
                    limit:10,
                    formPrefix : "dynamic_form",
                    normalizeFullForm : false
                });

                  dynamic_form.inject([{p_name: 'Hemant',quantity: '123',remarks: 'testing remark'},{p_name: 'Harshal',quantity: '123',remarks: 'testing remark'}]);

                $("#dynamic_form #minus5").on('click', function(){
                  var initDynamicId = $(this).closest('#dynamic_form').parent().find("[id^='dynamic_form']").length;
                  if (initDynamicId === 2) {
                    $(this).closest('#dynamic_form').next().find('#minus5').hide();
                  }
                  $(this).closest('#dynamic_form').remove();
                });

                $('form').on('submit', function(event){
                    var values = {};
                $.each($('form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
                    values[field.name] = field.value;
                });
                console.log(values)
                    event.preventDefault();
                  })
                });
            </script>
       
      <!-- fin prueba dinamica relatores -->
              </div> </div>      
            <br>
     <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">

                <a href="relatores_embed.php?keepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=280&amp;width=680" class="thickbox">    <h3>Si quiere agregar otro relator al listado, haga click aquí</h3>  </a>

       <input type="submit" name="enviar" onclick="valida_envia()" value="Enviar inscripción" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviar">
     </div>
            </div>
     </form>  
    </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

[Enlace donde tengo una prueba del sistema (Usuario: admin, contraseña: admin)](http://www.ceotalca.cl/prueba/cursos/creacion_curso.php)

Esto lo envia a un php donde guardo los datos en la BD:

```html
 $curso_nom = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `nombre_curso` FROM `cursos` WHERE `nombre_curso` = '$nombre_curso'"); 
         echo $curso_nom;
       
         if ($curso_nom==null){

         $sql = ("INSERT INTO `capacitaciones`.`cursos` (`nombre_curso`, `fechas_curso`, `horas_curso`, `id_ambito`, `codigo_sigper`, `vacantes`, `ubicacion`, `descripcion`, `id_relator`, `disponible`) VALUES ('$nombre_curso', '$fecha_curso', '$horas_curso', '$id_ambito', '$codigo_sigper', '$vacantes', '$ubicacion', '$descripcion', '$id_relatores', 'si')"); //Se insertan los datos a la base de datos y el usuario ya fue registrado con exito.  

         /*  $sql2 = ("INSERT INTO `capacitaciones`.`cursos` (`nombre_curso`, `fechas_curso`, `horas_curso`, `id_ambito`, `codigo_sigper`, `vacantes`, `ubicacion`, `id_relator`, `disponible`) VALUES ('$nombre_curso', '$fecha_curso', '$horas_curso', '$id_ambito', '$codigo_sigper', '$vacantes', '$ubicacion', 'dsffs', 'si');"); */

     if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {         
        scriptAlertGo('!El curso fue inscrito correctamente!','#');
      }else{
      scriptAlert('!Ha ocurrido un problema en la inscripción, por favor intente nuevamente!','#');
     }    
         }else{
          scriptAlertGo('El nombre del curso ya esta registrado en la base de datos','#');
         }
```

El problema esta en guardar las variables de id_relator, ya que estos son listbox con un script en javascript el cual agrega mas listbox a medida que el usuario necesite, pero al querer enviarlos al siguiente php me aparece el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id_relatores in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP5.3.0\www\capacitacion\cursos\creacion_curso_bd.php on
>   line 69

No se cual puede ser el problema, si alguien me puede guiar muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Bueno, tampoco es un error, es un aviso de que no has inicializado ese elemento del array. Te digo lo mismo de antes: para ayudarte necesito entender el problema y, para eso, tengo que poder depurar el código. Lo más sencillo es compartir el proyecto en un repositorio de GitHub o GitLab y pasarnos el enlace a ver qué vemos... Ya nos dices

Comment: Hola David; subí mi proyecto en un hosting de prueba,

http://www.ceotalca.cl/prueba/

Usuario y contraseña: admin

y la ruta donde aparece el problema (una vez agregado los datos del formulario) es http://www.ceotalca.cl/prueba/cursos/creacion_curso.php

Saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: No puedo ver la web porque el proxy me lo bloquea, pero hasta donde entiendo, quieres que un mismo name recoja varios valores. Siendo este el caso tienes la opción de agregar varios valores a un mismo name poniendo `name="miname[]"` y lo recoges por post o get, lo que mas cómodo te sea, en php. Puedes hacerle un implode() si quieres separarlo como string, pero tampoco es muy necesario si puedes trabajar con el array. Si es esto lo que necesitas te dejo aquí un código que uso yo para este caso concreto, si no lo es, matizame un poco mas que necesitas. Un saludo.

Comment: @JuanSalinas en el hosting podemos ver el resultado de lo que has programado, pero no podemos acceder al código fuente para poder ayudarte. Crea una cuenta en https://github.com/ y súbenos ahí tu proyecto, incluyendo un volcado en un .sql. Sin los ficheros no podemos localizar los números de línea para ver el motivo de los errores, hacer pruebas y demás tareas de depuración.

Comment: https://github.com/juansalinasaedo/capacitacion

Comment: Ahi subí los php creacion_curso.php y creacion_curso_bd.php , los que se encargan de registrar los datos

Comment: de antemano, muchisimas gracias

Comment: Emerita, es lo que necesito para mi formulario, si tienes el codigo a mano te lo agradeceria mucho, saludos